# DAG (Directed acyclic graph) - QAbstractItemModel

Tags: model-view-controller, qt, pyqt, implementation, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am planning on creating a Node Graph in pyqt.  The abstract models that qt provides work for 1D, 2D and Tree data but the abstract class seems to break down for something like a node graph.

In particular the "parent" function in QAbstractModel returns QModelIndex of a single parent.  In a DAG I will may have multiple parents.

One resource I found was this blog post:

http://invalidmagic.wordpress.com/2009/12/10/qgraphicsscene-used-as-a-qabstractitemmodel/

It provides some useful information, but I can't seem figure how the model represents the concept of multiple parents.

I'm looking for examples and suggestions for how to implement a DAG model in Qt.

Comment: I suggest you to head [here](http://socnetv.sourceforge.net/). Social Networks Visualizer (SocNetV) doesn't use MVC but I found worth it to delve into its source code.

Comment: QGraphicsScene is still a child with single parent model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread entitled [QTreeView display of graph (multiple parents of item)](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26204-QTreeView-display-of-graph-%28multiple-parents-of-item%29) is an interesting resource that you can consider (It also addresses using `QAbstractItemModel` for the case).

Comment: Thank you this seems like a good answer.  Its an authoritative discussion on the my exact problem. I am leaning towards using a Tree model but instead of representing connections through the parent and child relationship I will have both nodes and edges in the same hierarchy.  Children of the respective items will represent additional attributes.