# Qt tree model with items with multiple parents

Tags: c++, qt

I want to build a tree where one element can reference another. The tree I want to build is
something like this:

```
A
|--- B
|--- C
|    |--- D
|    |--- E
|
|--- F
     |--- P    //this is a "pointer" to C
          |--- D   //first child of C
          |--- E   //second child of C
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712559/dag-directed-acyclic-graph-qabstractitemmodel) and [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26204-QTreeView-display-of-graph-%28multiple-parents-of-item%29) regarding my question however no solution was found there.

The problem is implementing parent() in my `QAbstractItemModel`. Copying the elements is not possible, it could be a massive subtree (also I want them to be in sync when they change).

An item can have more than one parent in the model (the real parent, as well as the item currently pointing to it), how can I determine the currently correct parent?
Currently I just have an `Item*` stored in the `QModelIndex`, but when the `Item*` is currently `D` I can't find out whether the index means element `D` below `C` or below `P`.

I hope there is some way of working around this one to n parent-child mapping in Qt item models. I hope there is some way of doing this, otherwise I will need to implement my own widget which I would very much like to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to write a custom widget for this.

One solution would be to wrap your `Items`, such that each entry in your model holds not only an `Item*` but also some token that keeps track of its place in the tree.  Each node is now a separate entity (so you can easily implement `parent()`), but multiple nodes can refer to the same `Item`.

Comment: Yes, this should work. However the problem now is memory deallocation. I don't know how to free those tokens, since QModelIndex doesn't free the internalPointer()

Comment: You could use a shared pointer instead of a raw pointer to hold your Items.  When the last node referencing a particular `Item` is deleted, it will delete that `Item` as well.

Comment: @ar31, your indices should not _own_ data, it should only reference it. You should use some internal structure for _data storage_.

Answer (score 0):

For each item you can store a pointer to its parent. When you add a child to a node you can give a reference to `this` as a parameter to its constructor and you can set the parent of the item to be that reference.

Comment: I know, that is what I am already doing, the problem is that an item can have more than one parent.

Comment: Then it's not a tree and you should store the parents in a kind of collection, like an instance of the vector class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all,I just implement one treeview of items with multiple parents.
Just as what Tom W said,wrap my model data to treeitem.