# PyQt4: Is it possible to have items with multiple parents in a QTreeView?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreeview

I'm trying to visualize a model, where each object can have multiple parents. Minimal example:

```
root
  |--- parent1
  |      |--- child1
  |      |--- child2
  |--- parent2
         |--- child1
         |--- child3
```

I can't figure out how to properly visualize this model using the standard `QTreeView` widget.
I'm currently subclassing the `QAbstractItemModel` class for making my own model, but am unsure how to re-implement the `parent()` method, since it must return only a single index (the index of a single parent), as far as I understand. In the model above, `child1` would have two parents.

I've tried to have a look at [this almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677404/qt-tree-model-with-items-with-multiple-parents), but I'm a little lost at its answers, since that quesion regards the Qt implementation and not PyQt – and I'm no good at C++.